# Post sms as query string on aspx page

Tags: android

I'm trying to create an android app for new  incoming sms to post on my aspx page url as a query string and then I process on aspx page. I'm able to read inbox sms and post it by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.mywebsite.com/page.aspx?sms=sometext"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it want this process in background

Comment: For making network calls, see Volley or Retrofit

Comment: Thanks @MurtazaKhursheedHussain.! Now I'm able to make call with Retrofit.